# Auto adjust height of items wrapper div based on the largest div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As many of the designer might have faced issue with auto adjusting height of the all wrapper div to the height of the max height of the div.

Let us say I have following structure to show my blog items

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="blog-item">
        <div class="img">IMAGE</div>
        <div class="title">SOME TITLE</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="blog-item">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="title"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="blog-item">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="title"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="blog-item">
        <div class="img"></div>
        <div class="title"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and each blog items has an image and title and date associated with it. Title can be one line title or  two line title or three line. which makes it hard to adjust the height of the `blog-item` we can give `max-height` which usually works but add show extra space if this blog item and one line title. is there a ways we can auto adjust the height of `blog-item` wrapper based on the largest height on any `blog-item` div has taken.

In case we work with `max-height` then we have to assume max height of the `blog-item` otherwise design can break if title is larger than 3 lines

Comment: It is worth noting that, if pixel perfect compatibility with older IE versions is not vital, this task is [trivial with flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: `flexbox` can solve your problem.

Comment: `Flexbox` is `CSS3`..Since OP didnt add `CSS3` tag, I refrained from suggesting it.

Comment: would you mind js solution?

Comment: That is what i am trying to avoid... jquery.. but not ruled out.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is from [Ed Eliot's blog](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61)

Make divs/columns very very tall by adding a padding-bottom: 100% and then "trick the browser" into thinking they aren't that tall using margin-bottom: -100%(or)100%. It is better explained by Ed Eliot on his blog, which also includes many examples.

Sample code

```
.column {
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
 }
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/kaAjW/)

You can also use **flex/flexbox** if you want to adapt CSS3

Just set display property of outer div to flex

```
display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
```

Edit: Using flexbox with bootstrap [Demo here](http://www.bootply.com/126437)

Comment: Flex is breaking columns in bootstrap template and shows all of then in single row.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker Did you try the other method mentioned in Ed's blog?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker See the edit for an example usage of flexbox with bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

This solution is via jquery...

http://jsfiddle.net/mkdizajn/5ztns5sf/

```
var maxh = 0;
$('.column').each(function(){ 
   var currh = parseInt( $(this).height() )
   if( currh > maxh ){ maxh = currh }
});
$('.column').height( maxh )
```

Answer (score 1):

`flexbox` can solve your problem.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
    <div id="container">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <div class="blog-item">
              <div class="img">IMAGE</div>
              <div class="title">SOME TITLE</div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <div class="blog-item">
              <div class="img">image2</div>
              <div class="title">title2</div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <div class="blog-item">
              <div class="img">image3</div>
              <div class="title">title3</div>
              <div class="desc">long descriptions</div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          <div class="blog-item">
              <div class="img">image4</div>
              <div class="title">title4</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Problem with solution is that it breaks bootstrap column and shows all of them in single row.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker have you tried `flex-wrap` property? `flex-wrap: wrap;`

Comment: Yes it did, it also breaks bootstrap column structure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this has been asked many times, but I don't immediately see a question that gives the answer I'm looking for.

My standard (flexboxless) solution is table-like css. Simple: the entire row gets `display: table` and each column gets `display: table-cell`

In your case,

```css
.row {
  display: table;
}
.row > div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="blog-item">
      <div class="img">IMAGE</div>
      <div class="title">SOME TITLE</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="blog-item">
      <div class="img">image</div>
      <div class="title">longer
        <br/>title</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For a more complete discussion of some of the options, see https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Comment: I realized I was assuming that these go in a line together, based on the class names that look like "column". If you're talking about having the same height but not in a row together, that's a whole different problem

Comment: it also breaks in bootstrap.

Comment: You tagged it bootstrap, but you also tagged it jquery. Neither is necessary to achieve what you describe. For all we know you ended up with bootstrap just to try to solve this problem. Also, it doesn't break in bootstrap ;) there's other fine tuning to do, but the height problem is solved http://codepen.io/henry/pen/VLwrGJ (uses bootstrap)